# Liaison in Québécois: six minutes, dix minutes, six kilomètres etc

Tags: québec, liaisons

Is there liaison in these word combinations in Québécois?

- Two native French speakers, both teachers, both from Quebec, have given me contradictory answers.
- Google Translate has the liaison in its automated recording pronouncing them as *"di-minut"* [diminyt].
- Two Quebec speakers on the street have confirmed that /s/ **is** voiced in *dix minutes* [disminyt].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy/paste of the answer I provided here: [Six janvier, dix mars, etc](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24299/six-janvier-dix-mars-etc)
There are actually three possible situations, depending mainly on the word following six or dix:

1. If the following word starts with a consonant or an aspirated h, then the  final consonant shouldn't be pronounced. Examples : Le six mars, le dix mai, pronounced si and di.
2. If the following word starts with a vowel or a mute h, then the final consonant is pronounced as a (z). Example : Le six avril pronounced le sizavril.
3. In the other cases (mainly when six or dix are alone, or finishing a sentence, but also when they are used as a pronoun), the final consonant is pronounced (s). Example : Il m'en reste dix à faire (diss à faire). Le mot que tu cherches se trouve à la page six. (siss).
   Source : https://www.fpjq.org/pdfs/08-05_outils-nombres.pdf (along with my everyday experience of my native language).

To take in consideration : according to the region of France you live in, liaisons and pronunciation of a final letter are subject to change ; in the south, people are more up to pronounce the final x of six & dix as an s, less in the northern half ; there are even some regions (more in the north-eastern country) where the final t in vingt is being pronounced(but not the g), which always surprises me.

Comment: I agree about an ending "t" being sometimes pronounced in an isolated *vingt* in Eastern France, but I'm skeptical about a difference between Northern and Southern France regarding *six* and *dix*. Which of the rules 1., 2. or 3. do you believe is not followed, and where?

Answer (score 2):

In french, "x" of "*six minutes*" is not pronounced because of "*contraction des consonnes x et m*" rule.
However, if we ask "*combien de minutes?*", the response should be "six" (pronounced "sis").
When the same rule is is applied to "*dix minutes*", it gives "di-minut"

Comment: what about "kilométrés" ou "dollars"?

Comment: also would love to hear from somebody living in Quebec

Answer (score 2):

There's a pretty comprehensive write-up on *six* and *dix* on the [Québec banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3137) detailing when the final *x* is pronounced like an *s*, like a *z* or not at all.

To answer your question directly, the standard pronunciation of French would not voice the final *x* in your examples (i.e. pronounce like *si-minutes*, etc.):

> - As-tu vu les **six mignons** chatons? [simiɲɔ̃] (*si-mi-gnon*)
> - **Vingt-six mille** billets sont disponibles. [vẽtsimil] (*vin-tsi-mil*) [...]
> - Cette entreprise vaut environ **soixante-dix millions** de dollars. [swasãtdimiljɔ̃] (*swa-san-t-di-mi-li-on*)

Comment: Can someone from Quebec tell me if "x" at the end is pronounced SOMETIMES without the usual liaison rules (vowel in the beginning of the next word, etc), in a case such as six dollars?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not from Québec. I guess there could be regional variation but even in Québec I believe the dominant form is the one I referred to.

Comment: @Natalia See [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25507/liaison-in-dix-neuf/25517#25517). There are contexts in which you could say [dis] and even [diz]. As I noted there, here in Ontario I heard someone say "Dix dollars !" with a [z]. :)

Answer (score 2):

In term of word (category) combination, Num-Measure is a liaison context

> Deux z-euros

But most measure nouns are not liaison triggers. None of your examples feature liaison triggers (minute, kilomètre).

Quantifiers like 6 and 10 have a special property for French liaison, they have three different forms:

1. liaison context before a trigger (e.g. enfants): siz, diz
2. liaison context not before a trigger (e.g. personnes): si, di
3. not liaison context: sis, dis (six sont venus, dix ont séché)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.

It is pronounced "si-minut" and not "sis-minut". Same apply for "dix".

In fact, I can only found sample of "sis" and "dis" when enumeration number (i.e. in a standalone way).

Comment: It's not so simple, see "il y en a dix qui sont venus" where dix is pronounced diss.

Answer (score 0):

But for "dix mars", we could maybe say it both ways. Both *di-mars* and *dis-mars* could be used, although *di-mars* is probably the most common by a wide margin. *dis-mars* is not shocking to me though.

Comment: That's a very singular pronunciation. I never heard a native saying \dis maʁs\.

Comment: Now you have :-) I use it, probably for emphasis, sometimes. I'm not saying it's common by any stretch of the imagination, but it's not shocking to me.

Comment: "By a wide margin" is an understatement…