# Prononciation de « dix minutes »

Tags: prononciation, nombres

Selon les grammaires du français que je possède il faut dire

> Dix `/di/` minutes

où le *x* (habituellement `/s/`) ne se prononce pas.

Néanmoins, j'ai entendu pas mal de personnes prononçant « dix `/dis/` minutes » (idem. pour « six minutes »).

Pourquoi existe cette différence entre l'usage et la grammaire ?

Comment: Quelles grammaires ??? La prononciation n'a rien à voir avec la grammaire. La prononciation des consonnes finales est très variable selon les régions. Enfin... plusss... ou moinsss... du sud au nord.

Comment: Pour plus de détails: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25507/liaison-in-dix-neuf/25517#25517

Comment: Où as-tu entendu des gens dire *diss minutes* ? D'où venaient-ils ? Je ne l'ai jamais entendu de quelqu'un dont le français est la langue maternelle.

Comment: @jlliagre Un étudiant de Nîmes l'utilisé. On fait une pause de diss minutes plus précisément.

Comment: Ce devait être un étudiant espagnol...

Comment: ou québécois...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je suis francophone de naissance et j’utilise habituellement la prononciation `/di minyt/`, mais il y a des circonstances de la vie qui me pousseraient vers la pleine prononciation `/dis minyt/` (avec *minute* ou un quelconque autre mot commençant par une consonne ou un *h aspiré*) sans que je la ressente comme inappropriée. Ceci pourrait survenir par exemple :

- Lorsque je cherche un bref instant et évalue mentalement que je tomberais environ sur le nombre dix (`/dis/`), que je complète éventuellement avec des unités (par exemple des minutes) → la pleine prononciation indique davantage une hésitation qu’une maladresse grammaticale.
- Lorsqu’il y a correction d’une valeur donnée antérieurement, autant pour contredire la première que pour annoncer la nouvelle : « Pas cinq (`/sɛ̃k/`) minutes, non ! Dix (`/dis/`) minutes au moins ! »
      <sup>J’ai donné cinq minutes par souci de réalisme, mais six eût fonctionné tout aussi bien</sup>
- Si un enseignant indique à ses étudiants de laisser bouillir une mixture pendant dix minutes et désire insister sur le nombre afin qu’il soit bien noté et compris, l’ajout d’emphase mènera naturellement à la pleine prononciation : « Vous laissez bouillir **dix** (`/dis/`) minutes avant de réduire la température. »

Et il y a le cas des quantièmes, pour lesquels, du moins au Québec, la prononciation du nombre 10 est très majoritairement `/dis/`, autant devant voyelle que devant consonne :

- 10 janvier → `/dis ʒɑ̃vje/`
- 10 octobre → `/dis ɔktɔbʁ/`

Ce n’est pas un panorama complet du phénomène, mais ça montre certains cas où la prononciation varie sans que l’on doive y percevoir un accroc notable à la langue.

Answer (score 5):

Si vous avez un adjectif qui termine par un x et qui est suivi d’un nom commençant par une voyelle ou un h muet, vous prononcerez la lettre x comme un z. C'est une liaison.

*Il est deux heures. J’ai dix ans.*

Si par contre, un adjectif terminé par x est suivi d’un nom commençant par une consonne ou un h aspiré, la lettre x doit rester muette.

*Elle a dix jours de vacances. Il y a six lions.*

Il y a un cas particulier : dans les nombres *dix-huit* et *dix-neuf*, on prononce le x comme un z ([di.zɥit], [diz.nœf]). On prononce aussi parfois le x comme un s dans *dix-sept* : [dis.sɛt] ou [di.sɛt].

Pour ce qui est de dix et six, lorsqu'ils sont isolés, le x est prononcé effectivement comme un ss.

*J'en ai dix. J'en ai vu six.*

C'est surtout une question d'usage et non de grammaire.

Comment: Merci. Cependant, je connais ces règles dont vous parlez. Ma question est pourquoi pas mal de personnes pronnoncent diss (siss) minutes malgré avoir appris que ce n'est pas la correcte prononciation. Même des étudiants du supérieur.

Comment: C'est ce qu'on appelle couramment l'accent, ou autrement dit l'usage... Sans m'en rendre compte je prononce "vingT" dans certains cas : "Il est midi vingT". Ce qui n'est pas correct. C'est simplement un usage courant dans ma région.

Comment: @Reese : Tu es lorrain ?

Comment: @aCOSwt Rémois, ce n'est pas si loin.

Comment: Prononcer le *t* de *vingt* n'est pas incorrect, prononcer le *g* le serait. C'est l'usage qui définit la prononciation et cette variante est suffisamment répandue pour ne pas être considérée comme incorrecte, c'est même la prononciation standard en Suisse et en Belgique. De plus, la prononciation évolue. Contrairement à l'usage actuel, le *t* de *sept* ne se prononçait pas au XIXe siècle si suivi par un mot débutant par une consonne. Le rétablissement de la prononciation du *t* final est quasiment achevé pour *août* alors que les prononciations *a-ou* et *a-outte* sont en voie de disparition.